# SyntaxHighlighter Line numbers copy and pasted

Tags: javascript, syntaxhighlighter

How would I be able to get rid of line numbers for IE?  I already have `gutter:false` added in, but the line numbers get copy and pasted in IE (even though it does not show).

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a "copy" link or something that opens a popup window where users can copy the plain text from?

Answer (score 0):

with the latest version of SH - v3, line numbers are not copied when you copy code.